# How to take the path argument passed into vim/neovim into account when call `getcwd()` within the config?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

As title. I'm using NeoVim. If I use `vim.fn.getcwd()` in the config I will not get the correct path considering the argument, e.g. `nvim ./go/deeper/into/some/folder`, passed to `nvim`. Solutions in VimScript is welcome since I can translate it into lua one.

Comment: If you need the directory containing the first argument, try combining `fnamemodify()` with `argc()`/`argv()`, or `v:argv` if you need the full command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getcwd()` returns the current working directory of vim. By default it is the current working directory of the process that started vim.

In particular it is not the path of the folder of the file edited that you pass as argument to vim.

Comment: So is it possible to get the argument and combine them together?

Comment: I believe not while reading the .vimrc file. If you give us more information about what you would like to achieve I suppose we could guide you better on the way to achieve it. Why do you want to use the folder path of the file you pass as argument to vim?

Comment: you could try `:set acd`

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt: https://github.com/nyngwang/NeoRoot.lua, I'm the author. I want to skip the first step. "what you would like to achieve"... Hmmm, the best of me?